# Wpf Refresh Layout After Window StateChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

We have a wpf application. We use devexpress dock component.

In some computers, if the application stays minimized in the taskbar for a while, when we restore it, it freezes and takes time to work again normally.

Why does it behave like this? Does dispatcher sleep when it is minimized in task bar? How can i prevent it?

We test it in Windows 10, .net 4.5.

Edit: I think, after windowstate has changed, all layout is refreshed. That is the problem, but i couldn't find the solution.

Thanks,

Comment: It's probably just paged out all of it's RAM usage to disk.

Comment: How can i solve this? Thanks,

Comment: Maybe get more RAM!

Comment: The pc has 16 gb ram and more than half of it is free.

Comment: Any computation intense getter properties bound to view? I don't know whether WPF would re-query its bindings after a longer minimized time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. We are using devexpress dxwindow. When we omit it, it works normally.